# tensorflow import error with python

Tags: tensorflow

I have problem in importing Tensorflow module. Can anyone help me to solve the error? Please see the attached image for more details

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qnWU.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the URL of the package that was downloaded via the `pip` command, you'll see that it fetched the MacOS version, not the Linux version. This results in having an incompatible binary installed.

Note the optional step 2 in the [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#install_tensorflow) and try installing with an explicitly defined [package URL](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package).